# Can I use HTML5 download attribute for HTML forms?

Tags: html, forms

HTML5 introduced a nice feature for marking `<a>` links as download endpoints, by simply adding `download` attribute to the `<a>` tag [(see description)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

Is it possible to do the same for HTML forms?

Here is a simple use case for example: I have a form that requests the user for some details, and after the user submits the form the server should return a file according to these details.

Comment: Not sure if it's quite to the point or not, but if the main thing you want is for the "submit" operation to **not** affect page state (i.e. not to trigger the start of a navigation to the download URL), you can target a `_blank` window/tab, or better, put a hidden iframe on your page and target that.  (Of course this doesn't "mark" the form as a download endpoint to the programmer or to CSS via [download], as you might wish).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible.
According to the specification is the "download" attribute only specified for **a** and **area**.

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/links.html#downloading-resources

Comment: @StijnBernards: Why add code if there is no code involved? His answer is 'not possible'. What code did you want to see?

Answer (score 1):

No, `form` [doesn't have a `download` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp), so it is not possible to have that exact behavior with a `form`.

You can set the output file name through a post though, by setting the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourPicture.png"
```

Comment: @gamliela: Need more help?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm aware to `Content-Disposition` header. My question was specific about HTML forms.

Comment: That was the first sentence of my answer, right? I just don't like not giving options, and the `Content-Disposition` is the closest you get to the second part of the specs.

Comment: It’s not quite the same thing though. The more useful aspect of `download` is that it doesn’t cause all running AJAX requests to be cancelled and put the page in a weird state. A closer usable-now alternative I think would be something like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

Comment: @binki You could avoid changing page state by using `<form target "_blank">` (which does temporarily create a new browser tab when submitted), or better, `<form target="myHiddenIFrame">` targetting a hidden iframe on your page named "myHiddenIFrame" (which gets around the new-tab creation problem).  As long as you're *certain* the response will be a file to save and not a HTML page, this'll basically give you the same functionality as (the hypothetical) `<form download>` with no filename specified would (though I admit it's kinda clumsy).

Answer (score -1):

Yes after submitting data you can return file in form of pdf or else.
By using [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
<?php
//create pdf with details
.....
.
.
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
?>
```

But this is not possible using `download attribute`