# Change Content-Disposition filename with userscript from a Post

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

I would like to change the file name of a downloaded file from Submit that uses
`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Reports.csv`

I would like to Download that file with a preset file name
`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=AnyFileName.csv`

I would need it to be userscript friendly

The Download is Post and the content it returns is
`Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8`

I need it to change the filename of the download file

Answer (score 2):

That's not gonna be easy at all. To do this you will have to:

- send the form properly using either `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` API
- After sending, [retrieve the file data as `Blob`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12665440/607407). You need to use [`responseType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) to request `Blob`
- Use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create downloadable data URL
- Create link to allow download:

  ```
  <a href="${YOUR_DATA_URL}" download="AnyFileName.csv">Download</a>
  ```
- [Dispatch a click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) on that link
- Wait a bit (few ms) and then free the memory using [`URL.revokeObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)

I'm sory, it's probably much more work than you expected. Good luck. You may alternatively consider some add-on or program that tampers with the HTML headers for that particular site.

It would be much easier if you could use the `download` attribute on `<form>`, [but that's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26115548/607407).

Comment: Is there a Chrome Extension that can Change Download File name Based on URL?